# SQL Create view to count total number of orders

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-view

Please help create view for the task:

"Create a view containing information on the total number of orders for each book.
The view must contain two columns: "book title" and "number of orders"."

The book title is "name", table book - kniga and orders - zakaz

```
create view info_books as select kniga.name  from zakaz, kniga group by kniga.name;
select * from info_books;
```

But I guess I should get

```
name | count 
ee | 2 
ew | 1
few | 1
```

Here is my example: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gtXitKPGLYwz5QQPr1LZDX/2

Or here:

```
CREATE TABLE zakaz (
  `id_zakaz` INTEGER,
  `id_chit` INTEGER, 
  `data` INTEGER, 
  `id_knigi` INTEGER
);
CREATE TABLE kniga (
  `id_knigi` INTEGER,
  `author` CHAR(30), 
  `name` CHAR(30)
);


INSERT INTO zakaz
  (`id_zakaz`, `id_chit`, `data`, `id_knigi`)
VALUES
  ('1', '1', '123', '33'),
  ('5', '31', '414', '53'),
  ('7', '3', '523', '33'),
  ('4', '4', '52342', '54');

INSERT INTO kniga
  (`author`, `name`, `id_knigi`)
VALUES
  ('abc', 'ee', '33'),
  ('cfe', 'ew', '53'),
  ('feaq', 'fewda', '54');
```

Comment: You need a count aggregate function in your view/query see manual https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html and do change comma join to explicit join.

Comment: can you show an example please?

Comment: i tried this: 
```
create view info_books as
select kniga.name, zakaz.id_zakaz
from zakaz, kniga group by zakaz.id_zakaz;

select * from info_books;
```

Comment: `from zakaz, kniga` gives you a Cartesian Product. Please switch to explicit `join` syntax.

Comment: Why are you choosing to use archaic comma-based syntax instead of proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax?

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (**without errors**), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this query:

```
CREATE VIEW info_books AS
SELECT K.name, COUNT(*) AS 'Count'
FROM zakaz AS Z LEFT JOIN kniga AS K ON Z.id_knigi=K.id_knigi GROUP BY K.name;

SELECT * FROM info_books;
```